# ho to bind img src in file json to my template

Tags: image, vue.js

Hi I am starting with VueJS but I have a problem how to connect IMG src in my template with URL writing in my file JSON .for example when I have some product and I like to show full logo for each article I need to add URL exists in file JSON to src IMG .how I do that please thank

```
  <img src="info.imglogo" alt="Media Aside" />
  <span v-text="info.logotitle"></span>
 </template>
var infos = [
   {
       compteur: 1,
       imglogo: "../imgs/theme.jpg",
       logotitle: "Themeforest",
       title: "Thrive Themes",
       description:
           "Conversion Focused WordPress Themes & Plugins, built from the ground up to make your entire website convert more of your visitors into subscribers, customers & clients.",
       link1: "Visit ThriveTheme",
       link2: "Read Review",
       url: "../imgs/theme.jpg"
   },
   {
       compteur: 2,
       logotitle: "Elegant",
       title: "Sub-Ex",
       description: "com.goodreads.Tres-Zap",
       link1: "Dr",
       link2: "Honorable",
       url: "../imgs/theme.jpg"
   },
];

export default {
   data() {
       return {
           infos: infos
       };
   },
   name: "Home",
   components: {}
};
</script>
```

Comment: i highly recommend you to use tools like https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1):

like this.

```html
 <template>
  <div v-for="(info, index) in infos" :key="index">
   <img :src="info.imglogo" alt="Media Aside" v-if="info.imgLogo != undefined" />
   <span v-text="info.logotitle"></span>
  </div>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow:

```html
<img :src="info.imglogo" alt="Media Aside" />
```

Explanation:

> If you use variables and not text, you have to prepend your HTML attributes by ":"

Here is a working code. Replace your entire vue file by this one:

```js
    <template>
      <div>
        <div v-for="info in infos" :key="info.compteur">
          <img :src="info.imglogo" alt="Media Aside" />
          <span v-text="info.logotitle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "Home",
      components: {},
      data() {
        return {
          infos: [
            {
              compteur: 1,
              imglogo: "../imgs/theme.jpg",
              logotitle: "Themeforest",
              title: "Thrive Themes",
              description:
                "Conversion Focused WordPress Themes & Plugins, built from the ground up to make your entire website convert more of your visitors into subscribers, customers & clients.",
              link1: "Visit ThriveTheme",
              link2: "Read Review",
              url: "../imgs/theme.jpg",
            },
            {
              compteur: 2,
              logotitle: "Elegant",
              title: "Sub-Ex",
              description: "com.goodreads.Tres-Zap",
              link1: "Dr",
              link2: "Honorable",
              url: "../imgs/theme.jpg",
            },
          ],
        };
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: this would only work if he loops through this info array

Comment: when i have for example data of 100 person and i need to show photos on my template.how i use link of image  for each object and connect them with src

Comment: @jalloul try to make a working https://codesandbox.io then i can help you. i am sorry to say but for getting help on stack, you need a little bit more effort bro.